# sbt build on CloudBees gives "Name: No value provided for Name"

Tags: jenkins, sbt, cloudbees

I'm trying to set up an sbt build on a CloudBees-hosted Jenkins server.  The repository is stored in GitHub, and Jenkins is pulling the repository fine as I can see all the code in the workspace.

However, when I try to run the build I get the following output:

```
  ...
  Seen branch in repository origin/master
  Seen 2 remote branches
  Commencing build of Revision 763eecd49a522a50e53c6f24e40e5f2e984d3737 (origin/HEAD,    origin/master)
   Checking out Revision 763eecd49a522a50e53c6f24e40e5f2e984d3737 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
   Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here
   [ProjectName] $ java -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -jar /opt/sbt/sbt-launch-0.7.4.jar clean test
   Name: No value provided for Name
   Build step 'Build using sbt' changed build result to FAILURE
   Build step 'Build using sbt' marked build as failure
   Finished: FAILURE
```

The build runs fine on two other machines, even when run using an equivalent command line to the one Jenkins is using.  The project itself is a multi-project build with Play Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis is probably due to having the incorrect version of the sbt-launch jar in your global config's sbt section.  If you update it to say /opt/sbt/sbt-launch-0.13.0.jar that should resolve your problem